# How to Mass Update the Records of any Sobject in salesforce(Ex:Case,Lead,Opportunity,Task,Account,Contact)

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the Requirement to do a mass update on the records(EX:Case) on an sobject.

1) I have a custom button(List view button).I will select the records from the List View (Check box).On a click it has to take me to the page where i can put in the values necessary (Mass update).

Please direct me to a right direction.

Answer (score 2):

A simple search found the result in less than 30 seconds but maybe your tried that first and this may not be the answer you were looking for? If not please clarify your question.

> **Mass-Updating Records with a Custom List Controller**
>
> To create pages that perform mass updates, use the prototype object
>   contained in the StandardSetController class.
>
> The list controller tracks two sets of records: a primary list
>   containing all the records selected by the filter, and a secondary
>   list containing those records the user selected. The secondary list is
>   usually established on a standard listview page where the user can
>   check boxes to select the records. The user can then click on a custom
>   list button that navigates to your custom mass update page, which uses
>   the prototype object to apply new field values to the user's
>   selection. The prototype object operates on all the records in the
>   user's selection. To retrieve the prototype object in your custom
>   controller, use the StandardSetController's getRecord method. For
>   example, to enable mass updates for Opportunities, use the singular
>   term for its associated object (Opportunity) to set field values for
>   all records in the selection:

Remaining Information

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_massupdate.htm